# error message while running node.js application

Tags: node.js, npm

whenever I run a Node.js application I get this error only with this command 'npm run dev', but 'node app.js' will run without any issue.

Here is the error
[image]

Please let me know what is the issue, I tried uninstalling the node.js but it did not work.

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: here is the package https://github.com/secvisogram/csaf-validator-service, I was not able to send package.json file

Comment: try changing the dev command in package.json to just `nodemon server.js`